# How to customize error message using jQuery.validator placeholders?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to add custom form validators. And I'm stuck with message customizing issue.

Let's say I want to check if field value does not exceeds max allowed value.
I know that 'Validation Plugin' has a "max" validator already - this is just for sample:

```
$.validator.addMethod("max-numeric", function(value, element, param) {
    var maxValue = $(element).attr("data-max");
    return (!maxValue) || maxValue >= value;
}, $.validator.format('Applicants must be older than {0} and younger than {1} years of age'));

$("#data-form").validate({
    rules: {
        "form.params1.p4":
        {
            "min-numeric": [5, 6]
        }
    }
});
```

I cannot comprehend what is responsible for replacing {0} and {1} in '$.validator.format'. And how to pass those parameters?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the message I get:

> Applicants must be older than true and younger than [object
>   HTMLInputElement] years of age

Comment: The method is called `max-numeric`, but you're referencing `min-numeric` in the `rules` object of the  `.validate()` method.

Comment: @Sparky This is what happens after 15 hours of non stop coding ). Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will make any difference here, but I've found that enclosing the message in `$.validator.format()` seems to always be totally unnecessary.  I've yet to find one instance that breaks when I remove it.

Comment: @Sparky I just check it - Yes, it works without it. And it looks much better. I guess I'll have to go through docs to find if its eligible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot comprehend what is responsible for replacing `{0}` and `{1}` in `'$.validator.format'`. And how to pass those parameters?

In your example above, `{0}` represents the first parameter and `{1}` represents the second parameter.   The parameters are `[5, 6]` respectively and the automatic replacement of such within the message is handled automatically by the plugin.

So when writing a custom method, there is nothing special you'll need to do.  If you pass three parameters into your method...

```
customMethod: [34, 50, 10]
```

...then you'll have `{0}`, `{1}`, and `{2}` available for your custom message, representing each value of the parameters respectively.

It just works.

---

If there is something going wrong, then it's not obvious from your OP aside from:

> The method is called `max-numeric`, but you're referencing `min-numeric` in the rules object of the `.validate()` method.

As long as you have two parameters next to `max-numeric`, then your example would work.

```
max-numeric: [5, 6]
```